# Create Colour Wise Multiple Lines Of Particles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am creating particle animation using Canvas & JavaScript. Currently, particles are generating from an emitter randomly & falling in a direction (top right corner to bottom left corner). collision detection effect is also working on mouse hover.

problem is:
I want to create separate color-wise multiple lines of particles (e.g:- blue colored particles should be in separate a line & red in a separate line).
how could I achieve this?

[image]

Sorry for bad drawing, any reference will be very useful. Thank you in advance.

```js
(function() {
                var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
                function(callback) {
                    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
                };
                window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
            })();

            var particleArr = [],
            canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
            flakeCount = 700,
            mouseX = -100,
            mouseY = -100,
            xMultiplier = 0.015
            
            canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
            canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

            var rate = 0.07788656582264941;

            function getRandomColor() {
                // Random Color Generate
                const colorArr = ["rgba(215,88,69, 1)", "rgba(117, 161, 199, 1)"]; // Blue & Orange Color
                const randomColor = colorArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArr.length)];

                return randomColor;
            }

            function flow() {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                 
                for (var i = 0; i < flakeCount; i++) {
                    var flake = particleArr[i],
                        x = mouseX,
                        y = mouseY,
                        minDist = 150,
                        x2 = flake.x,
                        y2 = flake.y;

                    var dist = Math.sqrt((x2 - x) * (x2 - x) + (y2 - y) * (y2 - y)),
                        dx = x2 - x,
                        dy = y2 - y;
                    
                    if (dist < minDist) {
                        var force = minDist / (dist * dist),
                            xcomp = (x - x2) / dist,
                            ycomp = (y - y2) / dist,
                            deltaV = force / 2;
                            // deltaV = 0.03960597468566516
                            
                        flake.velX -= deltaV * xcomp;
                        flake.velY -= deltaV * ycomp;

                        // flake.velX -= deltaV * xcomp + rate;
                        // flake.velY -= deltaV * ycomp + rate;

                    } else {
                        flake.velX *= .98;
                        if (flake.velY <= flake.speed) {
                            flake.velY = flake.speed
                        }
                        flake.velX += Math.cos(flake.step += .05) * flake.stepSize;
                    }
                
                    flake.y += flake.velY;
                    flake.x += flake.velX;                    
                        
                    if (flake.y >= canvas.height || flake.y <= 0) {
                        reset(flake);
                    }

                    if (flake.x >= canvas.width || flake.x <= 0) {
                        reset(flake);
                    }

                    ctx.fillStyle = particleArr[i].color;
                    
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(flake.x, flake.y, flake.size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
                    ctx.fill();
                }
                
                requestAnimationFrame(flow);

                // setTimeout(() => {
                //     requestAnimationFrame(flow);
                // }, 1000 / 40);
                
            };

            function reset(flake) {
                let temp = (Math.random() * 1) + 0.5;
                flake.x = canvas.width;
                flake.y = 50;
                // flake.size = (Math.random() * 3) + 5;
                flake.size = 6.692053245649504;
                flake.speed = (Math.random() * 7) + 0.5;
                flake.velY = flake.speed;
                flake.velX = -xMultiplier  * canvas.width * temp;
                // flake.opacity = (Math.random() * 0.5) + 0.3;
            }

            function init() {
                for (var i = 0; i < flakeCount; i++) {
                    var x = canvas.width,
                        y = 50,
                        size = 6.692053245649504,
                        speed = 0;
                        
                        // size = (Math.random() * 3) + 5, // can change 3 to 4 
                        // speed = (Math.random() * 1) + 0.5;
                        // opacity = (Math.random() * 0.5) + 0.3;
                        
                    particleArr.push({
                        speed: speed,
                        velY: speed,
                        velX: -xMultiplier  * canvas.width  * speed,
                        x: x,
                        y: y,
                        size: size,
                        stepSize: (Math.random()) / 30,
                        step: 0,
                        angle: 360,
                        color: getRandomColor()
                        // opacity: opacity
                    });
                }

                requestAnimationFrame(flow);
                //   flow();
            };

            canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
                mouseX = e.clientX,
                mouseY = e.clientY     
            });

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            function onWindowResize() {
                canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
                canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
            }

            init();
```

```css
canvas{
                background-color: #000000 !important;
            }

            body {
                margin: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
            }`
```

```html
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: It seems like an easy problem ... Instead of using `getRandomColor` set the color based on the velocity vector of the particle?

Comment: I need to create two colours of particles, & colour wise multiple streams of particles

Comment: actually I am new to canvas programming, if else statement is not an issue, I am not understanding what you are saying velocity means

Comment: Is this your code?  what are you doing here: `flake.velY = flake.speed;` ... and here:                  `flake.velX = -xMultiplier  * canvas.width * temp;`  ... anyone reading that would assume that `vel` stands for velocity, that determines the direction the flake moves, set the color from that.

Comment: flake.velX = -xMultiplier  * canvas.width * temp; this line is used to fall particles in a direction, I have already tried to add colour the way you suggested, but instead of expected output, it is making colour flicker issue to the particles

Comment: if the color flickers is because you keep changing the color, just set the color once and done